# Using 2 servers for TFS, what to install where?

Tags: tfs, build, server

Quick question:

I have two servers, and the initial idea was to use one as application-tier and data-tier, and the other one as build machine.

But it's a relatively small project, so it seems like total overkill to use one server only for the build services (I was assuming a weaker machine would come, then I got surprised).

If I do split app tier and data tier between the two servers, where should I put the Build Service?

On the app tier side or on the data tier side? Which one would be better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our environment, we have the AT and DT separated on their own machines, and host a build service on the AT. What it comes down to is where you have the most "spare" resources available for the build machine.  Take a look at perfmon counters for memory and CPU over time, and see which one looks like it is the most lightly used, and put your build agent there.

From experience, that's likely to be your application tier, particularly if you've got the reporting services and the cube installed on the data tier along with the source code repository and work item store.